# CSS truncate strings past two lines

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have an item "gallery" with the name of the item above the image. I am loading all information from an xml file so I need the strings to be modified dynamically at two lines adding "..." to the end of the strings that are too long. is there a way to do this? I'd prefer an answer in JS but any language will do.

here is the code for the gallery portion of the page.

```
<?php

$GO = $game->gameobjects;

$sets = $GO->sets;

foreach($sets->set as $set) {

 echo"    <h3>$set->name</h3>\n";

 echo"    <div class=\"gallery\">\n";

 $objects = $set->objects;

 foreach($objects->object as $object) {

  $url = genurl("$base->name" . "." . $object->img, "png");
  $name = trimtext($object->name, 20);

  echo"     <div class=\"item\">
      <div class=\"item-name\" title=\"$name[title]\">
       $name[name]
      </div>
      <img src=\"$url\" class=\"item-img\"/>
     </div>\n";
 }

 echo"    </div>\n";

}
 ?>
```

I was hoping by truncating the text at a certain string length would work but 20 characters could still span 3 lines or more and I want two lines max.

Comment: Please show some code and make a choice of the preferred language for an answer. As of now the question is way too broad and might be closed due to that reason.

Comment: @thepio I have added code, and specified a language that I would prefer my answer be in.

Comment: thanks for adding all this information! I added an answer below with Javascript example for you.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.text-limiter {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-limiter">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet nunc.<br>Sed nonummy gravida. In eros diam sed urna. Nunc at ipsum. Vestibulum ante ipsum orci, id leo ac risus. Sed sed lacus. Curabitur arcu vitae ante. Lorem ipsum feugiat est, at magna. Vestibulum ante ipsum nibh, volutpat massa dui eget enim. Mauris lobortis eu, rhoncus purus, congue eleifend. Nulla dolor dictum accumsan lorem. Vestibulum convallis cursus a, mattis sem. In cursus dignissim erat a neque mauris, interdum malesuada. Donec sit amet, libero. Donec nec adipiscing elit. Curabitur ultrices velit nulla a mi. Cras nec pede. Pellentesque placerat. Curabitur et turpis. Cras ipsum sed neque. Phasellus hendrerit magna iaculis odio, a mi. Fusce convallis eu, auctor tortor id purus est, at sapien. Etiam varius nec, mattis a, convallis tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean augue egestas dignissim, libero at turpis. Duis aliquam, purus lacinia neque. Nunc leo. Curabitur scelerisque mauris vitae odio condimentum ac, cursus wisi, posuere cubilia Curae, Donec pulvinar gravida, eros eros sed justo ac nunc iaculis at, molestie aliquam. In nec ligula placerat quam. Phasellus posuere cubilia Curae, Quisque rutrum, urna.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css

```
.item-name{   
     display: -webkit-box;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
     -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

...or cut in php (if you know how many symbols must be)

```
function my_crop($text, $length)
{
    if ($length <= 0 || strlen($text) <= $length)
        return $text;
    $out = mb_substr($text, 0, $length);
    $pos = mb_strrpos($out, ' ');
    if ($pos)
        $out = mb_substr($out, 0, $pos);
    return $out.' &hellip;';
}
```

and use *my_crop($name[name], 20)* within *$name[name]*

..or look, what you have in array $name, cause string

```
  $name = trimtext($object->name, 20);
```

looks like already trimming something

Comment: Doesn't work with IE, Edge or Firefox. Would not recommend if browser support is any issue.

Comment: added cross-browser issue ))

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Javascript example for you. You need to set the `max-height` and `overflow` of the div though. In my snippet there are two ways to do it. With id or by class (for multiple elements).

```js
function lastLineEllipsWithId(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  var wordArray = el.innerHTML.split(' ');
  while (el.scrollHeight > el.offsetHeight) {
    wordArray.pop();
    el.innerHTML = wordArray.join(' ') + '...';
  }
}

function lastLineEllipsWithClass(elementClass) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(elementClass);
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var wordArray = elements[i].innerHTML.split(' ');
    while (elements[i].scrollHeight > elements[i].offsetHeight) {
      wordArray.pop();
      elements[i].innerHTML = wordArray.join(' ') + '...';
    }
  }
}

lastLineEllipsWithId('box');
lastLineEllipsWithClass('box');
```

```css
#box {
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
.box {
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
.box2 {
  height: 70px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <b>ID BOX</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
  aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<div class="box">
  <b>CLASS BOX</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
  aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<div class="box box2">
  <b>CLASS BOX</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
  aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

This works also with set width etc (as seen in the last example). Overall when the div is overflowing it will ellipsis the last line that is visible.

Comment: I think that in mobile devices first two boxes will have 3 lines instead of 2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this [approach](https://jsfiddle.net/ivan0013/dpu8t00s/1/).

Instead of truncating the text, just hidde it. Create a wrapper with a `max-height`, this measure should be `number of desired lines * 1 line height`.

Note that this is responsive and cross-browser.